# Impossible to center exactly li's inside a div

Tags: html, css

Please, give me some help in the following:

HTML code:

```
<div id="medium_ribbon">        
    <ul class="up_rectangles">
        <li id="first_up">&nbsp;</li>
        <li id="second_up">&nbsp;</li>
        <li id="third_up">&nbsp;</li>
        <li id="fourth_up">&nbsp;</li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Next, CSS code:

```css
#medium_ribbon {    
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#172236;
    padding-top:20px;   
}
.up_rectangles{
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;     
}
.up_rectangles li {
    line-height: 200px;  
    width: 265px;
    background-color: #C8CACF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.up_rectangles>li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Finally, the result:
[image]

The picture is a bit aligned to the right and I cannot discover the reason no matter how much I've tried.
Thank you

Comment: No, you are not right!

Comment: You've got 40px of padding-left on your `.up-rectangles` that's coming from somewhere. Just set padding 0 for this element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser's default stylesheet automatically puts padding on `.up_rectangles`.

Simply reset if by applying this CSS rule:

```
.up_rectangles{
   padding: 0;
}
```

Then it will work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/R8pL3/

Answer (score 2):

by default `<ul>` have some `padding` and `margin`.

So add the `margin:0` and `padding:0` in `.up_rectangles' class.

so the code will be like.

```
.up_rectangles
{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0   
}
```

Comment: Once you are satisfied with the answer you should accept the answer, so in future other people can easily get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-left:0` to your `.up_rectangles` class. The browser, be default, adds padding to `ul` elements. By adding `padding-left:0` to the `ul` you'll fix this.

```
.up_rectangles{
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px; 
  padding-left:0;    
}
```

Here's the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/X4bm7/).